# Migration Wordpress to a new host issue

Tags: linux, backup, wordpress, migration

I migrate a wordpress site to a new host (my server with ISP Config 3) .... same domain. I downloaded backup for Home Directory  and Database from old host... I created a new DB on my server.... I imported DB backup, I changed wp-config with new DB name, user and password. When I have accessed domain in browser only homepage works, if i try to access mydomain.com/wp-admin... i received a blank page or a 404 message.Rewritemod is enable.

I tried to install a fresh wordpress on a free domain and with the fresh install on the free domain the website works.

---

I found the problem .... MySQL from old host is  "5.5.51-38.2 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.2, Revision 727" and from new host is "10.0.26-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)"

Comment: Did your backup contain the .htaccess file and did you recover it ?

Comment: Yes my backup contain .htaccess and it contains only WordPress rules..

Comment: Did you check Apache/Nginx log files for more information?

Comment: The database can sometimes contain the path on the server. A find and replace before you upload the database can fix it.

Comment: I tried that, but did not work.

Comment: Is MariaDB really the problem, as per your update? A dump from MySQL that's imported into MariaDB should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB and MySQL share basically the same libraries so it's not likely that MariaDB is the issue. When you change hosts your document root path also (usually) changes. This can affect many Wordpress functions. Make sure you've searched and replaced the database and files for the old path and have updated it with the new one.

It's possible that permalinks need to be reset as well and don't forget to clear any cache from caching plugins.